# India specific- Addressing multiple men and women in an interview

Tags: formality, indian-english

**In an interview in India, how am I supposed to greet the people (all of them together) in the interview panel?**

The interview panel consists of **at least two men** and **at least two women**.

> Good morning, Sirs and Ma'ams <sup>C-1</sup>

or just

> Good morning, respected interview panel members

How am I supposed to greet them **(all of them together)**?

*The interview may be considered as a formal interview for government job or for college admission or anything similar*

---

Edit:

I tried to find transcripts. Below are some interview transcripts of UPSC (Civil service) exam interviews  <sup>C-2</sup>. These are possible cases of two or more men, and one woman.

1. [Good afternoon sirs, madam](https://byjus.com/free-ias-prep/upsc-interview-transcript-chakresh-mishra/)
2. [Good evening Ma’am, Good evening sirs](https://byjus.com/free-ias-prep/upsc-interview-transcript-by-kamnashish-sen-board-p-k-mishra)

---

<sup>C-1. I would make sure it's pronounced /mæm/ and not "Madam". I am not sure about the "Madam" issue as pointed in comment. I will take the time to understand it later. Pronouncing /mæm/ is common and absolutely fine as far as I know.</sup>

<sup>C-2. A reputed exam in India</sup>

Comment: I realize you're explicitly asking about Indian English, which may differ from what I know, but in other standard varieties of English, "Sirs and Madams" would sound very awkward in this situation. Especially right now, "Madam" evokes possible [negative connotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghislaine_Maxwell). "Ladies and gentlemen" would be much more typical.

Comment: Related (but not duplicates): [Is it alright to say good afternoon Sirs and Madams in a panel interview?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/221568/9161) [What are some polite ways to address a group in a forum post?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/54733/9161)

Answer (score 2):

"Good morning" is sufficient.

It is the role of the leader of the panel to control the start and pace of the interview.  He or she will invite the interviewee in, direct them where to sit and introduce other members of the panel. The interviewee responds to questions from individual panel members, but *the interviewee does not address the panel as a group*. There is no need for "Sirs and Madames" or "respected interview panel members" and using such phrases can be seen as sarcastic.

> Prof. A: Ah, Good Morning Mr Snape,  do take a seat.
>
> Snape:  Thank you.
>
> Prof A. Now, this is the formal part of the interview.  This is Dr B, who you met during your tour. She is head of the department. And to my right is Mr C who works in student support.
>
> Mr C. Hello.
>
> Snape: Good morning Mr C.
>
> Prof A: Now I'll begin.  Tell me,  why do you want to join our university...

In Indian English, it is acceptable for the interview to say "Good morning sir" (or ma'am) when speaking to a particular person

> Mr C: Hello
>
> Snape: Good morning, sir.

But this should be avoided in other dialects, in this context.

Comment: Since you are talking about what's ok in Indian English -- do you happen to be aware of any guides to the differences between Indian English and American (or e.g. British) English? From the American side, I'm aware of a small number of major differences that happen to come up in my field, but I'm curious about others.

Comment: Indian English is a low prestige dialect, my knowlege is based on first hand experience with Indian English speakers, who freely use "sir" without irony, in contexts that I would find inappropriate.  As a low prestige dialect, there are unlikely to be "guides"  (a native speaker of a high prestige dialect such as "British English with RP" is unlikely to want to study to learn to speak like a Bombay native.  There are some short guides on the internet, and probably some sociolinguistic studies in academic journals.

Comment: @JamesK What do you mean by “low prestige dialect”?